# Is the closure of a subset of $\Bbb R$ the collection of all its interior and boundary points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have learned the definition of the closure of $A$, as the set $\overline A$, of all the points and limit points of $A$. It occurred to me that maybe the closure is also the set of all interior and boundary points of $A$. I did a very long and boring proof which goes as follows :

Let $x\in \overline A$. Suppose $x\in A$. If $x\in int(A)$ then we are done. If $x\notin int(A)$, then since $x\in A$, it must be a boundary point of $A$. 
Now suppose $x\notin A$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $A$. So each neighborhood of $x$ contains $x$, which is a point not in $A$, and a point in $A$. So it is a boundary point. 
Conversely, if $y$ is an interior point of $A$, then it is a limit point as well. Suppose $y$ is a boundary point of $A$. Either $y\in A$ or $y\notin A$ and in the latter case, $y$ being a boundary point, must be a limit point of $A$. This completes the proof.

I want to know a simpler, more intuitive reasoning as to why this is true; and whether this is true in other topological spaces. I have used a fact that is true *because* we are in $\Bbb R$ - interior points are limits points. This leads me to believe the result isn't true in general.

Comment: The closure can also be thought of as the smallest closed set containing $A$.

Comment: limit points are not needed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any subset $A$ of a topological space $X$, there is a three-way partition of the space : $$X = \operatorname{int}(A) \cup \partial A \cup \operatorname{int}(X \setminus A)$$

where all three sets are pairwise disjoint. (If $x \in X$, *some* neighbourhood of $x$ stays inside $A$, or *some* neighbourhood of $x$ stays inside the complement of $A$, or finally, *all* neighbourhoods of $x$ intersect both $A$ and its complement.)

Also, $$X\setminus \overline{A} = \operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)$$

which is clear by the definitions too: $x$ is not in the closure of $A$ iff there is *some* neighbourhood of $x$ that misses $A$ iff there is some neighbourhood of $x$ that stays inside the complement of $A$.

Combining these two facts indeed:

$$ \overline{A} = \operatorname{int}(A) \cup \partial A$$

and this holds for all spaces $X$ and all subsets $A$ of $X$.